# perl can't see path problem ubuntu 20.04.4 anaconda

Tags: 20.04, python, perl, anaconda

Hi Im trying to run pfam_scan.pl (bioinformatics)

Im using conda but theres is perl from ubuntu system... Its conflicts with another? Or script can't see modules?

```
$ pfam_scan.pl 
Can't locate Moose.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Moose module) (@INC contains: /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4 /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.32/site_perl /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.32/vendor_perl /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl /home/marcin/anaconda3/lib/perl5/core_perl .) at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/Bio/Pfam/HMM/HMMResultsIO.pm line 50.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/Bio/Pfam/HMM/HMMResultsIO.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/Bio/Pfam/Scan/PfamScan.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/Bio/Pfam/Scan/PfamScan.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/pfam_scan.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/marcin/anaconda3/share/pfam_scan-1.6-4/pfam_scan.pl line 8.
```

Comment: Have you installed the relevant modules? Do you have more than one perl installation? Maybe the system one and another you have installed through conda? If so, does it work if you run `/home/marcin/anaconda3/bin/perl pfam_scan.pl` (make sure to change `/home/marcin/anaconda3/bin/perl` to the right path for your conda perl executable). Finally, don't you need some input there? A fasta protein sequence and a set of HMM models?

Comment: See the comment from *terdon*. Also, if you do not get an answer here quickly, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/).

Comment: @terdon Hey still same... if script will run without input etc. Help page is displayed.

Comment: @TimurShtatland will try

Comment: @MTG if you do ask on [bioinformatics.se], please remember to delete this question first. What does "still same" mean? What did you try exactly? And you haven't answered my main question: *have you installed the relevant perl modules*? The error tells you that you need to install the Moose module, have you done so?